# Explain Subquery na parent query

Tags: mysql

sub query will be execute before parent query and subquery pass result to parent query.... but in bellow parent query use sub queries result...........
[image]

```
 $sth = $conn->query(
    "SELECT tab.AttDate AS Salman,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendence_info WHERE AttStatus='P' AND AttDate=Salman) AS Monu,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendence_info WHERE AttStatus='A' AND AttDate=Salman) AS Janu FROM attendence_info AS tab GROUP BY tab.AttDate"
);
```

Comment: Is not clear what you are looking for .. please expose your question

Comment: sub query will be execute before parent query but in here subquery is using parent query select item(tab.AttDate). if subquery execute first then how does tab.AttDate contain value.......??

Comment: In SQL before and after are not proper  .. you mus think in term of set theory .. anyway i have  post an answer .. because you code seems wrong to me ..

Answer (score 0):

In the way you have formed the query the accessing to the value tab.AttDAte and attData = Salman are independent each other .. is like are two separated query  .. any way when and if the value match could be you have omogeneus behavior.

Comment: my query run successfully but I want to explain this query

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth = $conn->query(
    "SELECT tab.AttDate AS Salman,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendence_info WHERE AttStatus='P' AND AttDate=Salman) AS Monu,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendence_info WHERE AttStatus='A' AND AttDate=Salman) AS Janu FROM attendence_info AS tab GROUP BY tab.AttDate"
);
```

tab.AttDate of parent query and AttDate of Subquery come from same attendence_info Table. tab.AttDate is just alias for making different but both contain same column value....
So subquery can use tab.AttDate